# Multiple Star Review on Same Page

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a multi-page form and on one of the pages I have a star-review application, whereby users can vote between 1 and 5 stars. I have it working great, however on the same page I need this multiple times (i.e. different things to review).

I have tried a number of things; changing the class of 'stars' and 'star', but neither allows multiple ratings - they all trigger back to the first one (i.e. if you select 2 star on the second it also defaults the first selection to 2 star, or only selects the first selection to 2 star). Any ideas?

HTML code:

```
<div class="stars">
    <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" />
    <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" />
    <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" />
    <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" />
    <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" />
    <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form .stars {
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form .stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
  width: 100%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
  width: 80%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
  width: 60%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
  width: 40%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
  width: 20%;
}
form .stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .stars label:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
  width: 80% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
  width: 60% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
  width: 40% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
  width: 20% !important;
}
form .stars span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: The `name` attribute in your `input` elements has to be unique for each review. It's the variable that contains the value. Your backend doesn't magicly know which review posted a value.

Comment: So change "name=____" for each one? I'm fairly sure I already tried this but it didn't make any difference. I'll try again though.

Comment: Well there's a bit more to it than that. But without your backend code, I can't help you any further.

Comment: What do you mean by "backend" code?  This is where I got my code from, nothing more to it than this: http://voidcanvas.com/make-simple-star-rating-by-radio-buttons-using-css/

Comment: The PHP code. The part that actually saves the ratings? What's the point of having ratings on your website if they aren't saved anywhere?

Comment: Oh wait.. Now I understand your problem. It's not the saving of the values, it's the CSS design.. my mistake

Comment: I haven't even worked into the backend yet, so I will work that out when I come to it. That was not my question. I have not posted my backend because right now I am not trying to work on that. I am trying to see if I can even have 2 reviews on the same page otherwise working out the backend is redundant.

Comment: Yes I understand the issue now. I'll see if I can work something out

Comment: Well I know why it's happening, but couldn't figure out a straight forward solution. Instead of using a class as a selector, you could use a unique id. This allows you to target each Review seperately without causing interference. But it'll also increase the amount of CSS required exponentially and it'll limit you to a certain amount of Reviews per page.  I suppose a better solution would be use a combination of CSS and Javascript or jQuery to get this done. But that's behond the scope of an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by changing the radio name and keeping IDs unique.

Radio buttons are grouped by name so that each represents a value for a particular form "variable". With each set of stars representing a different variable, a product's rating, each group should have a separate name reflecting which product they're for e.g. appending the product id, `name="star-123456"`. You could also append the index of the product in the list of items for the form.

IDs should always be unique among elements. In this case the radio input ids should be unique for the labels' for attribute to point to the right one.

The snippet below contains unique names for the two radio groups and unique IDs for each radio input.

```css
form .stars {
  background: gray;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form .stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
  width: 100%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
  width: 80%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
  width: 60%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
  width: 40%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
  width: 20%;
}
form .stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .stars label:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
  width: 80% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
  width: 60% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
  width: 40% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
  width: 20% !important;
}
form .stars span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-1" id="star_a-1" />
        <label class="star-1" for="star_a-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-2" id="star_a-2" />
        <label class="star-2" for="star_a-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-3" id="star_a-3" />
        <label class="star-3" for="star_a-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-4" id="star_a-4" />
        <label class="star-4" for="star_a-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-5" id="star_a-5" />
        <label class="star-5" for="star_a-5">5</label>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-1" id="star_b-1" />
        <label class="star-1" for="star_b-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-2" id="star_b-2" />
        <label class="star-2" for="star_b-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-3" id="star_b-3" />
        <label class="star-3" for="star_b-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-4" id="star_b-4" />
        <label class="star-4" for="star_b-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-5" id="star_b-5" />
        <label class="star-5" for="star_b-5">5</label>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</form>
```