# Multiple 5 Star Review Rows HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

**Hello,**
I'm trying to build a 5 star rating form where I want to have 3 rows of 5 star rating. Here's what I have:

```css
.ratingLabel {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Light',Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding: 8px 0;
  float: left;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.rating {
  float: right;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label,.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
  <label class="ratingLabel">Friendly advisor:</label>
  <div class="rating">
    <input id="star5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5"/>
    <label for="star5" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star4.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
    <label for="star4.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3"/>
    <label for="star3" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star3.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
    <label for="star3.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2"/>
    <label for="star2" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star2.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
    <label for="star2.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="star1" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star1.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
    <label for="star1.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star0"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="star0" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star0.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
    <label for="star0.5" class="half"></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
  <label class="ratingLabel">Call line quality:</label>
  <div class="rating">
    <input id="star5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5"/>
    <label for="star5" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star4.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
    <label for="star4.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3"/>
    <label for="star3" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star3.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
    <label for="star3.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2"/>
    <label for="star2" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star2.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
    <label for="star2.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="star1" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star1.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
    <label for="star1.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star0"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="star0" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star0.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
    <label for="star0.5" class="half"></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
  <label class="ratingLabel">Overall satisfaction:</label>
  <div class="rating">
    <input id="star5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5"/>
    <label for="star5" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star4.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
    <label for="star4.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3"/>
    <label for="star3" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star3.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
    <label for="star3.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2"/>
    <label for="star2" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star2.5" name="rating" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
    <label for="star2.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="star1" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star1.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
    <label for="star1.5" class="half"></label>
    <input id="star0"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0"/>
    <label for="star0" class="full"></label>
    <input id="star0.5"  name="rating" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
    <label for="star0.5" class="half"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see **live** from the following **[link](http://apespark.com/formify/examples/review32132132.html)**, the selection is simply not working. Tried naming the 3 rows differently and giving them different IDs, still didn't work.

Comment: attribute `id` cannot contain `.`

Comment: Take a look at this, it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991572/multiple-star-review-on-same-page?rq=1

Comment: Seems that you have got a problem with your code. Once I tried to rewrite your code, it's working. Isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello guys,**
Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991572/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991572/multiple-star-review-on-same-page?rq=1), I've managed to fix it. The link to the question and answer I provided can be considered universal solution to those cases. Here's the change to the *HTML* I applied:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="ratingLabel">Friendly advisor:</label>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <input id="star_a-5" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-5" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-45" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-45" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-3" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="3"/>
                        <label for="star_a-3" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-35" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-35" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-2" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="2"/>
                        <label for="star_a-2" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-25" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-25" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-1" name="rating_a" type="radio" value="1"/>
                        <label for="star_a-1" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-15"  name="rating_a" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-15" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-0"  name="rating_a" type="radio" value="0"/>
                        <label for="star_a-0" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_a-05"  name="rating_a" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
                        <label for="star_a-05" class="half"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="ratingLabel">Call line quality:</label>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <input id="star_b-5" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-5" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-45" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-45" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-3" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="3"/>
                        <label for="star_b-3" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-35" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-35" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-2" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="2"/>
                        <label for="star_b-2" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-25" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-25" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-1" name="rating_b" type="radio" value="1"/>
                        <label for="star_b-1" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-15"  name="rating_b" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-15" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-0"  name="rating_b" type="radio" value="0"/>
                        <label for="star_b-0" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_b-05"  name="rating_b" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
                        <label for="star_b-05" class="half"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-s-8 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="ratingLabel">Overall satisfaction:</label>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <input id="star_c-5" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-5" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-45" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="4.5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-45" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-3" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="3"/>
                        <label for="star_c-3" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-35" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="3.5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-35" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-2" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="2"/>
                        <label for="star_c-2" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-25" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="2.5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-25" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-1" name="rating_c" type="radio" value="1"/>
                        <label for="star_c-1" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-15"  name="rating_c" type="radio" value="1.5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-15" class="half"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-0"  name="rating_c" type="radio" value="0"/>
                        <label for="star_c-0" class="full"></label>
                        <input id="star_c-05"  name="rating_c" type="radio" value="0.5"/>
                        <label for="star_c-05" class="half"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```